# How to reset ssl certificate exceptions in chromium?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, chromium

TL:DR;

How does one reset chromium's ssl certificate(s) to its default behavior (as if freshly installed on a new operating system)?

---

I've found posts that say to go to Edit => Preferences => Advanced Settings => Change Proxy Settings => ...?

I'm unable to get further as the following message is displayed:

> When running Chromium under a supported desktop environment, the system proxy settings will be used. However, either your system is not supported or there was a problem launching your system configuration.
>
> But you can still configure via the command line. Please see man chromium-browser for more information on flags and environment variables.

(No command line options seem available for clearing/resetting ssl certs - This according to chromium-browser --help or man chromium-browser)

I am using vagrant to generate a server. On this server, an Nginx web server is installed and a self-signed certificate is generated. When browsing to the Nginx url, I'm encountering behavior that I can't explain. Sometimes browsing to the site url provides a warning but provides the option to add an exception, after which I can browse to the site. Other times I receive the following error and am presented with no other options:

> This site can't provide a secure connection.
>   [url] doesn't adhere to security standards.
>       ERR_SSL_SERVER_CERT_BAD_FORMAT

In Firefox, I can reset the ssl certificates and proceed as needed, but in chromium, I'm not sure how to clear out previous exceptions. I would expect that ssl certificate exceptions might be listed within the HTTPS/SSL => "Manage certificates" area of the Advanced Settings, but the certificate/exception is not listed anywhere within that dialogue box (or related tabs).

Any tips, hints, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

- K.E.

Answer (score 2):

The process that ended up working was:
"Edit" => "Preferences" => "Show Advanced Settings" => "Privacy" => "Clear Browsing Data" => (select time period) => -[X]- "Cached Images and Files" => "Clear Browsing Data".

I expected that SSL Certificate Exceptions would be stored somewhere within the "Edit" => "Preferences" => "Show Advanced Settings" => "HTTPS/SSL" => "Manage Certificates" section, however this was not the case (at least, not for the self-signed certificate I was using from the chef-server I'd been working with).

As a side note, its seems that there is an issue currently with Chromium (v58) which seems to be the cause of the chef-server's self-signed certificates coming back with a `ERR_SSL_SERVER_CERT_BAD_FORMAT` error. Both Chrome (v59 on Ubuntu 17.04) and Firefox (v54 on Ubuntu 17.04) are able to read the self-signed certificate as expected and allow traffic to proceed.

Details of the issue can be found at:
https://textslashplain.com/tag/certificates/
(Again, this is my best guess to the cause of the issue after considerable time researching on the web).